# What is the best server environment to resist massive traffic with Drupal?

Tags: php, web-server, reverse-proxy, drupal, configuration

I am setting up a Drupal website that might have critical traffic for a while. What is the best setup (distro, apache/ngynx/lighttpd, reverse proxy, sql server, php version, etc) to handle it?

Drupal configurations/modules are welcome, as well.

Comment: Define "critical traffic"? Anonymous users? Authenticated users? What are they doing? HTTP? HTTPS? Mixed?

Comment: anonymous users, http, huge number. (there will be authenticated users, but it will be fewer than five users...)

Comment: this has picked up my attention: http://drupal.org/node/583264#rsync (mirroring with boost module + rsync)

Comment: What is a huge number? A hundred, a thousand, ten billion, what? You need to supply real detail, rather than just some vague notions, to allow others to determine just what your needs are.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple resources:

http://2bits.com/sites/2bits.com/files/drupal-single-server-3.4-million-page-views-a-day.pdf

http://groups.drupal.org/node/21897

To summarize: use APC and Memcached, try to limit the number of Drupal modules you use and be judicious with your logging (e.g. use syslog to write Drupal events to a file instead of to the Database).

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Given the majority of users will be anonymous, I would highly recommend Pressflow and [Varnish](http://www.varnish-cache.org/)

Here is [a list](https://wiki.fourkitchens.com/display/PF/Who+uses+Pressflow) of high profile / traffic Drupal sites using Pressflow.    If you do some benchmarking before and after implementing varnish you'll be very happy with the increase in req/sec.

Comment: is pressflow compatible with boost?